# C programming, stacks, printing stack error

Tags: c, printing, segmentation-fault, stack, syntax-error

My professor gave us a code to write and part of the code she gave us was to print what we put into a stack. However, as I have already made her aware of as well, it does not correctly print what is in the stack. It throws an error that means to me that after printing the info in the stack it tries to continue because it does not actually empty the stack. My question is, Anyone have a solution to this? Here is the code fragment she gave us:

```
    void print_stack(stack s)
    {
        if (!is_empty(s))
        {
        printf(“%d\n”, s->data);
        print_stack(s->next);
        }
    }
```

It correctly prints the numbers in the stack but then throws a segmentation fault in PuTTY and and exception in Visual Studio. After pushing these numbers (1,2,3) onto the stack, it prints:

3
2
1
-1991643855

Segmentantion fault (core dumped)

In Visual Studio it simply says:

Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.

s was 0xCCCCCCCC.

Thank you in advance.

The push code is:

```
void push(stack*s, int num)
{
    stack temp;
    temp = (stack)malloc(sizeof(struct stacknode));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = *s;
    *s = temp;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that does " pushing these numbers ... "  Problem is there (likely in the first push) or it is used wrong.

Comment: Edited post above to contain it

Comment: "temp->next = *s;". Shouldn't it be "temp->next = s;"?

Comment: When you initialize stack s in main(), do you initialize it to NULL? 

It looks like it is uninitialized and, set to 0xCCCCCCCC, quite randomly. Because it does not start off with stack s initialized to null, the is_empty() call will not detect that you are at the end of the stack, and so will try to access this invalid address, and give you a segmentation fault. In your main() function, declare your stack s as "stack *s = NULL;", then call push, etc.

Comment: ScottK- After looking over the code I realized I was indeed not initializing it to NULL. I had it set to do so. However, I did not call the function at the beginning of main to begin the initialization. It was a small oversight. Your post was the most helpful as it was closest to the correct reason for my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize stack s in main(), do you initialize it to NULL?

It looks like it is uninitialized and, set to 0xCCCCCCCC, quite randomly. Because it does not start off with stack s initialized to null, the is_empty() call will not detect that you are at the end of the stack, and so will try to access this invalid address, and give you a segmentation fault. In your main() function, declare your stack s as "stack *s = NULL;", then call push, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense for struct stack's next member to be a pointer. So shouldn't
"temp->next = *s;". Shouldn't it be "temp->next = s;"?

"*s" is a dereferenced pointer, which is a value.

PS: I'd appreciate an edit, I'm on web mobile :)